# Relation between an indefinte and definite integral

Tags: definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

How is the following relation established?
$$
\int e^{-p r^2} d\mathbf{r}=4 \pi\int_0^\infty r^2 e^{-pr^2} dr
$$
where $p$ is a real and positive number.

Comment: This doesn't seem right, or at least it is imprecise. The left hand side is a function of $r$ and the right hand side is a number.

Comment: @Marcus Aurelius In fact this is a conversion of indefinite integral to definite one which is used in my textbook to obtain a final result.

Comment: Are you sure the LHS integral is not wrt $dv$ (volume) and implicitly over all of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: @ancientmathematician Actually No! My textbook is old and typography is not clear. I took a photo of this part and uploaded it [here](https://ufile.io/csvro). Let me know what happen if your guess is true.

Comment: I have edited the question; in your scan the integral on the LHS is wrt $d\mathbf{r}$ and not $dr$. I think if you write $\mathbf{r}$ in spherical polars you'll get the result. Also in the previous lines it seems to me that the integral on the LHS is over the whole space.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thanks a lot. I need to know how RHS is obtained, because I have another integral which must be converted to a definite one in a way similar above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that $d\mathbf{r}$ means here the volume integral and that the integral on the left is over all $\mathbb{R}^3$.

If we pass to spherical polars $(r,\theta,\phi)$, and remember the formula for the volume element,  then the integral will become
$$
\int_{r=0}^{\infty}\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{\phi=0}^{\pi} e^{-pr^2}\ r^2\ \sin\phi\ dr \ d\theta\ d\phi
$$
which evaluates to the RHS.

Comment: That's Right! Thank you so much. This was one of the disadvantages of an old textbook!